Teams webhook payload - How to delete border and descrease the height of message
I currently use webhook in Microsoft Teams to send message. It's works but I am not satisfied with the rendering because the message is not compact. There's a lot of wasted space...

How to delete border?
How reduce spacing in facts element?
Why there are spacing between header (logo, text, hour) and border ?

Do you suggest me something to improve my payload ?



{
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "summary": "test",
            "content": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "version": "1.5",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Hello <at>User</at> ",
                        "wrap": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "FactSet",
                        "height": "stretch",
                        "facts": [
                            {
                                "title": "MSISDN",
                                "value": "123456789"
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "ICCID",
                                "value": "1234556789912345"
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "CF",
                                "value": "xxxxxxxx"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ActionSet",
                        "actions": [
                            {
                                "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                                "title": "Google",
                                "url": "http://google.com"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "msteams": {
                    "entities": [
                        {
                            "type": "mention",
                            "text": "<at>User</at>",
                            "mentioned": {
                                "id": "test@test.com",
                                "name": "Myname"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}




These above mentioned changes are not supported. Supported formats are mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cdesktop%2Cconnector-html.
